# Removing dynamically generated textboxes in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I've spent most of my time working with PHP/HTML, and a small script I'm writing for my sanity (Paperwork, way too much paperwork.) has forced me to use JQuery.  I've Searched on Google, SO, and more, but I haven't found anything close to resembling the code I'm currently using or I get lost in the language.

The code below is basically an dynamic form, with the ability to add text boxes as required.  Each new generated text box is required (HTML5) for the form submission, but if I create an extra text box that's unneeded, I would like to be able to remove it (So it doesn't leave me with a field I don't need, and can't submit the form because it's required).

JFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/fmdx/jZU97/ (using JQuery 1.10.1)

HTML

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="customcheck" name="custom" href="#custom">Custom Exceptions Needed?</div>
<div id="custom" style="padding-left:40px;">
    <input type="text" id="exception_1" placeholder="Six foot utility..."><br>
</div><!-- Ending Custom Div -->
<div style="padding-left:40px;"><a id="add_field" href="#"><span>Add Another Exception</span></a>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
var counter = 1;
$(function () {
$('a#add_field').click(function () {
    counter += 1;
    $('#custom').append(
        '<input id="exception_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="text" placeholder="Six foot utility..." required><a href="#">Remove</a><br>');
     });
});
```

The Basis of the code above I got off of a tutorial that includes on how to take all of the information submitted through these dynamic forms and put them into a database.  So, I'm really trying to use this code specifically.  (Tutorial: http://www.infotuts.com/dynamically-add-input-fields-submit-to-database )

Thanks for any help or advice in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By only adding a class to your delete button, you can do what you want with this code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.add($this.prev()).add($this.next()).remove();
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jZU97/5/

But using `.next()` and `.prev()` is not really recommended, so i would suggest you regroup your added input into a div (1 for each one added) and use `.closest('div')`.

Comment: I think that you should target the exact remove button when you attach click listener to it. What if there is another .remove button.

Comment: Yes, it works, but what you are doing is attaching a listener to a *.remove* link, div or whatever element on the page has this class. Imagine that there is another element at the footer of the page with the same class. It will get the same listener. You should attach the event the the exact element.

Comment: @Krasimir IMO, you should be aware of what class you are using, just do not duplicate 2 of the same class if they do not have the same purpose...

Comment: Yep. That's a good advice, but the truth is that shit happens and in a big project with several developers there is always someone which will make the mistake to use the same class.

Comment: True, but anyway, with delegated event, you can change the `$(document)` for the closest static parent, which will not target `.delete` in the, for example, footer. But sure, attaching direct event is always better than attaching delegated ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your jsfiddle edited http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/jZU97/6

The idea is to wrap the input field and the button in a div.

```
var counter = 1,
    custom = $('#custom');
$(function () {
    $('a#add_field').click(function () {
        counter += 1;
        var newRow = $('<div class="row' + counter + '"><input id="exception_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="text" placeholder="Six foot utility..." required><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove-text-box">Remove</a></div>');
        custom.append(newRow);
        (function(index) {
            newRow.find('.remove-text-box').click(function() {
                custom.find('.row' + index).remove();
            });
        })(counter);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OR

you can use delegate (attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements) of jquery

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 1;
$(function () {
    $('a#add_field').click(function () {
        counter += 1;
        $('#custom').append('<div id="addedField_' + counter + '"><input id="exception_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="text" placeholder="Six foot utility..." required><button onclick="$(\'#addedField_' + counter + '\').remove()">Remove</button><br></div>');
    });
});
```