# dynamically add, validate and remove sets of form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to create a webpage where the user can add and remove sets of form fields by means of one add button and remove buttons related to the set to be removed. Entered values will be checked by means jquery validate, for which rules are added dynamically as well. pls see an an simplified example below of my targeted form:

What is a good structure of javascript code for adding, removing and validate sets of forms fields? I googled -also on this site- and there are many javascript examples for adding sets of formfields. I like the example I found at view-source:http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/demos/jqueryvalidation/testadd.cfm, which uses a form template. But I struggle in particular with the javascript coding for the removing buttons..(which are not in the example)

my targeted (simplified) form (template with 1 set of 3 formfields):

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="">
  <input id="name1" name="name1" />
  <input id="email1" name="email1" />
  <input id="phone1" name="phone1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should template the form. I.e. wrap it in a function, so you can create it again and again. Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/2sZsx/4/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<a href="#" id="add-form">add form</a>
```

JS

```
var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
var addForm = $("#add-form");
var index = 0;

var getForm = function(index, action) {
    return $('\
        <form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="' + action + '">\
          <input id="name' + index + '" name="name' + index + '" />\
          <input id="email' + index + '" name="email' + index + '" />\
          <input id="phone' + index + '" name="phone' + index + '" />\
          <input type="submit" value="Save">\
          <a href="#" class="remove">remove form</a>\
        </form>\
    ');
}

addForm.on("click", function() {
    var form = getForm(++index);
    form.find(".remove").on("click", function() {
       $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    wrapper.append(form);
});
```

Comment: thnx, very useful (!) From your example I noticed I didnot describe my context clearly as the various form sets are supposed to be in a single form (with a single save button). But I can work that out from your example. One would add jquery validation rules within the addForm onclick function, correct?

Comment: Yep, eaxactly. You may attach more events to *form* and actually write the validation using the same approach.

Comment: thnx. my validation code does not go right yet. I added "$("#email"+index).rules("add", { required:true,email:true });" below the 'wrapper.append(form);' statement and then added the validate() function below the addForm function. Any idea what could go wrong?

Comment: The validation should be done once the user submit the form. Are you doing it then or ...

Answer (score 0):

Simple validation can be done when your form is submitted, thus:

```
$('#myForm').submit({
    var n1 = $('#name1').val();
    var e1 = $('#email1').val();
    var p1 = $('#phone1').val();

    if (n1=='' || e1=='' || p1=='') {
        alert('Please complete all fields');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note that the `return false` will abort the submit and return user to the document.

---

Great code for adding/removing form fields can be found in this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520384/removing-dynamically-generated-textboxes-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520384/removing-dynamically-generated-textboxes-in-jquery#18520490)

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jZU97/5/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using KeenThemes (maybe Metronic theme)
https://preview.keenthemes.com/good/documentation/forms/formvalidation/advanced.html

You can do like this.

```
var form = document.getElementById('form_id');
var validator = FormValidation.formValidation(
  form,
  {
      fields: {
          name: {
              validators: {
                  notEmpty: {
                      message: 'Please enter template name'
                  },
                  stringLength: {
                      min: 3,
                      trim: true,
                      message: 'Please enter a longer  name.'
                  },
              }
          },
          ...
            more fields here
          ...
      },
      plugins: {
          trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
          bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap(),
      },
  });


function addNewFieldDynamically() {
    // add new field here
    ...
    validator.addField('field_name', {
        validators : {...}
    })
}

function removeFieldDynamically() {
    // remove a field here
    ...
    validator.removeField('field_name')
}
```